# Two-dimensional array used as translation to copy and paste rows

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I have a spreadsheet that calls out jobs with agents assigned.  The "agent ID" is in column A, with data in columns A-M.

I have separate sheets for each of the agent's supervisor (supervisor last name).  I was hard coding the agent ID into the macro but I would like to make it work so I could pull that data from a translation sheet which would hold nothing more than the agent ID and corresponding supervisor last name.  I can't figure out how to parse through the data row by row, find the agent id, then copy that row to the corresponding sheet.

I already have the translation sheet (named sup-agent_Trans) with AgentID, Supervisor; that's it, those two columns.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Dim varList As Variant
Dim lstRowTrans As Long
Dim lstRowRework As Long
Dim rngArr As Range
Dim rngRwk As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lstRowTrans = Worksheets("Tech-Sup_Trans").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lstRowRework = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

varList = Sheets("Tech-Sup_Trans").Range("A1:B" & lstRowTrans)

Set rngRwk = Sheets("Rework").Range("A1:A" & lstRowRework)

For Each cell In rngRwk
For i = LBound(varList, 2) To UBound(varList, 2) 'columns
    If i = cell(i).Value <> "" Then
        For j = LBound(varList, 1) To UBound(varList, 1) 'rows
            If varList(j, cell(i).Value) Then
            IsInArray = True
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
Next cell
```

Comment: Good point... No, I did not write this code.  I borrowed this code and changed it to work for me.  I'm beginner level in VBA, so I kind of know what it's doing, but I can't wrap my head around arrays and how to lookup one value and return another

Comment: oh man...  I'll start messing around!

Comment: can you give me a stronger hint?  LOL

Comment: Edited my original post to show my progress...  Thoughts?

Comment: `IsInArray = True` lol what is this? `varList = Sheets("Tech-Sup_Trans").Range("A1:B" & lstRowTrans)` is a range I think not array. There are other problems but good effort. So what's wrong?

Comment: Isinarray went to a different function but I killed that idea... It hasn't found any values yet, parses through the right column looking at TechID, but it never "finds" the value in the array.  The range is where that data is entered by the user so when there are edits to tech/sup reports, this macro will automatically pick them up... Is there something different to use than array?

Comment: So, I don't know exactly how the data is laid out but your original code worked right? You just wanted not to hard code IDs into array? So all you have to do is fill the array dynamically.

Comment: You, the original had hard coded ID and now I want to be able to have the end user put the ID in one column with the Supervisor in the next column...  So it would have all ID and who those ID report to (supervisor).  So when the macro runs, it would look up the ID, then find the corresponding supervisor for the ID and move that row to that supervisor's sheet.

Comment: Someone else asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417425/excel-vba-syntax-errors-compiling-issues/37417632#37417632).

Comment: so I don't even have to use the "array" ... Wow, genius! ...  Thanks, I'll start using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

So after someone so graciously pointed out that I don't need to use an array, I used the "Find" function for a range and figured it out.  Thanks findwindow!

```
Dim shtRwk As Worksheet
Dim shtRef As Worksheet
Dim DestCell As Range
Dim rngRwk As Range
Dim lstRowTrans As Long
Dim lstRowRework As Long
Dim rngArr As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim strSup As String

Set shtRwk = Sheets("Rework")
Set shtRef = Sheets("Tech-Sup_Trans")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lstRowTrans = shtRef.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lstRowRework = shtRwk.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Set rngRwk = Sheets("Rework").Range("A2:A" & lstRowRework)

For Each cell In rngRwk
    With shtRef.Range("A1:B" & lstRowTrans)
        Set DestCell = .Find(What:=cell.Value, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not DestCell Is Nothing Then
            strSup = DestCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            cell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets(strSup).Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            shtRwk.Select
        Else
            MsgBox "No Sup found for tech " & cell.Value
        End If
    End With
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```