# Excel VBA Syntax Errors & Compiling Issues

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a simply copy+paste values where the macro will take a date that populates into a cell, searches for the date in the next sheet, and pastes the values from A2:X2 where it finds the date.

Sub Copy_PasteVal()

```
Dim dDate As Range
Dim shtTrack As Worksheet
Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim DestCell As Range

Set shtdata = Sheets(“Daily Total”)
Set shtTrack = Sheets("Overall Daily Tracking")
Set dDate = shtData.Range(“A2”)

Worksheets("shtData").Range("A2:X2").Copy
With Worksheets(shtTrack).Range("a1:a1000")
    Set DestCell = .Find(dDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
Worksheets(“shtTrack”).Range(DestCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

End Sub

It's not compiling and I'm hoping some gurus out there can help me figure out coding in VBA!

Comment: `from A2:X2 where it finds the date` what if the date is not found on row 2??

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: I don't know if it's the formatting here on SO, but your quotes in your sheets need to be `"`.  Some of yours are more "stylized", such as `Worksheets(“shtTrack”).`  replace that with `Worksheets("shtTrack").` (same with `Daily Total` at the start and `dDate`.

Comment: Thank you Bruce!

Though now I'm getting the error:
Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range 
 Worksheets("shtData").Range("A2:X2").Copy

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I may have it backwards? Also, not sure if you intended to wipe out column A...

```
Dim dDate
Dim shtTrack As Worksheet
Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim DestCell As Range

Set shtData = Sheets("Daily Total")
Set shtTrack = Sheets("Overall Daily Tracking")
dDate = shtData.Range("A2").Value
Set c = shtData.Range("A2:X2")

With shtTrack.Range("a1:a1000")
    Set DestCell = .Find(dDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not DestCell Is Nothing Then
        r = DestCell.Row
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

With shtTrack
    .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 24)).Value = c.Value
End With
```

Comment: Those are some nice looking quotes :D  (@Jatell, since you were wanting the values only when pasting `xlPasteValues`, a much quicker way (and avoids using the Clipboard) is to set the two ranges equal to eachother, like findwindow did in the second to last line. That's a nice "trick" to learn)

Comment: Thats a great tip, thank you!

Unfortunately, Im still getting the "Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range" error for the "with worksheets..." line.

Comment: @jatell Ooops, you already qualified `shtTrack`. Please see edit.

Comment: @jatell Wait, do I have this backwards?

Comment: @findwindow yeah you had it backwards! the edit is better, thank you; however, I'm getting an error on the 'r = DestCell.Row' line.

Should we define the variable 'r'? if so, as what? Long or Range?

Comment: @findwindow

thank you! if nothing is getting copied into the desired cells, that tells me there is an error going on in my .Find, correct?

Comment: No, that means nothing was found.